# код не работает помогите найти ошибку

Tags: javascript

Собрать информацию о 15 пользователях (фамилия и возраст). Для хранения информации использовать двумерный массив. С помощью функции найти всех пользователей, старше 14 лет.

```
var KOLOBOK=[];
KOLOBOK=[
["Волочков",13],
["Деркач",14],
["Лемешенко",14],
["Горячев",15],
["Гусак",3],
["Продан",5],
["Кушнир",13],
["Кувайкин",13],
["Колесник", 18],
["Семенович", 9],
["Мухин",14],
["Фомин",14],
["Рубашов"17],
["Бабаловский",15],
["Раканов",12] ]
function srawn(x)
{
if (x>14)
}
return true;

for(var i=0; i < KOLOBOK.length; i++) {
if(KOLOBOK[i][1] > 14) alert(KOLOBOK[i][0] + " старше 14 лет")

}
```

Comment: просмотрите фигурные скобки...и допишите код до конца

Comment: Весь код выложите.

Comment: не работает,что  может быть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Расставь запятые после каждого элемента массива (кроме конечного).
2) Функция крайне странная, лучше так:

```js
var KOLOBOK=[
  ["Волочков", 13],
  ["Деркач", 14],
  ["Лемешенко", 14],
  ["Горячев", 15],
  ["Гусак", 3],
  ["Продан", 5],
  ["Кушнир", 13],
  ["Кувайкин", 13],
  ["Колесник", 18],
  ["Семенович", 9],
  ["Мухин", 14],
  ["Фомин", 14],
  ["Рубашов", 17], // Тут в Вас запятой нет в внутреннем массиве
  ["Бабаловский", 15],
  ["Раканов", 12]
];
function getUsers(arr, func){
  arr.forEach(function(e){
    if(e[1] >= 14)
      func(e[0]);
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  var res = document.querySelector('#result');
  getUsers(KOLOBOK, function(e){
    res.innerHTML += e + " старше 14 лет<br />";
  });
});
```

```html
<div id='result'></div>
```

Выполняет переданную функцию для всех элементов, которые "старше" 14.

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь!!

Comment: Если не сложно объясните пожалуйста,  как так получилось?

Comment: @tania-31, Что именно объяснить?

Comment: Всех детей старше 14, стало выводить в вашей функции?

Comment: Функция принимает Ваш массив первым аргументом и функцию для обработки элементов, которые старше 14. Т.е. те, кто 13 и ниже не выполнятся.
В функции массив перебирается встроенной функцией `forEach`, там проверяется - текущий элемент старше или равен 14? Если да, то выполняет переданную функцию и передаёт аргументом имя.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! за оказанную нам помощь.

Comment: @tania-31, Нам?

Comment: TheDoctor, сын  изучает   и мне помогает осваивать  javascript

Comment: @tania-31, Тогда нужно начинать с самых основ. Можно даже отсюда: https://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/ru/

Answer (score 0):

В коде выше были проблемы в синтаксисе.
Можно использовать такой вариант:

```
var KOLOBOK = [
    ["Волочков", 13],
    ["Деркач", 14],
    ["Лемешенко", 14],
    ["Горячев", 15],
    ["Гусак", 3],
    ["Продан", 5],
    ["Кушнир", 13],
    ["Кувайкин", 13],
    ["Колесник", 18],
    ["Семенович", 9],
    ["Мухин", 14],
    ["Фомин", 14],
    ["Рубашов", 17],
    ["Бабаловский", 15],
    ["Раканов", 12]
];

(function(x) {
    for(var i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i][1] > 14) alert(x[i][0] + " старше 14 лет")
    }
})(KOLOBOK);
```

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь!!!